# Populate sqlite database from JSON array with Core Data one-to-many relationship

Tags: json, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to read data from a JSON file and store it into sqlite. I am getting the "simple" data through, but I can't figure out how to get the one-to-many relationship item from my array into sqlite.

Here is my Data Model:

(Sorry - they won't let me do a screen capture here... so here is a description of the data model:)

```
    Entity: SeasonInfo 
    Attributes:
    year
    coach
    wins
    losses
    ties
        Relationship: players
        Destination: PlayerInfo
        Inverse seasonInfo

    Entity: PlayerInfo
    Attributes:
    name
    number
       Relationship: seasonInfo
       Destination: SeasonInfo
       Inverse: players
```

Here is my JSON:

```
    [
       { "year": 2012, "wins": 8,  "losses": 8, "ties": 0, "coach": "Garrett",
          "players": [ { "name": "Tony Romo",  "number": 9},
                      { "name": "Dez Bryant",   "number": 88} ],
       },
       { "year": 2011, "wins": 8,  "losses": 8, "ties": 0, "coach": "Garrett",
         "players": [ { "name": "DeMarcu Ware",  "number": 94},
                       { "name": "Felix Jones ",  "number": 28},
                       { "name": "Miles Austin",  "number": 19} ],
        },
        { "year": 2010, "wins": 6,  "losses": 10, "ties": 0, "coach": "Garrett/Phillips",
          "players": [ { "name": "Sean Lee",      "number": 50},
                       { "name": "Jason Witten",  "number": 82} ],
        }
     ]
```

Here is my Code :

```
    // Load JSON data into Array
    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CowboySeason" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* cowboySeasonsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                                  options:kNilOptions
                                                                    error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported Seasons: %@", cowboySeasonsArray);


    // Export data from the array into the database

    // Store the SeasonInfo 
    [cowboySeasonsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        SeasonInfo *seasonInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SeasonInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

        seasonInfo.year = [obj objectForKey:@"year"];
        seasonInfo.wins = [obj objectForKey:@"wins"];
        seasonInfo.losses = [obj objectForKey:@"losses"];
        seasonInfo.ties = [obj objectForKey:@"ties"];
        seasonInfo.coach = [obj objectForKey:@"coach"];

        seasonInfo.players = [obj objectForKey:@"players"];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

cowboySeasonArray looks like this in the log:

```
    2013-02-25 20:39:05.025 SeasonTestLoader[369:503] Imported Seasons: (
    {
    coach = Garrett;
    losses = 8;
    players =         (
                    {
            name = "Tony Romo";
            number = 9;
        },
                    {
            name = "Dez Bryant";
            number = 88;
        }
    );
    ties = 0;
    wins = 8;
    year = 2012;
},
    {
    coach = Garrett;
    losses = 8;
    players =         (
                    {
            name = "DeMarcu Ware";
            number = 94;
        },
                    {
            name = "Felix Jones ";
            number = 28;
        },
                    {
            name = "Miles Austin";
            number = 19;
        }
    );
    ties = 0;
    wins = 8;
    year = 2011;
},
    {
    coach = "Garrett/Phillips";
    losses = 10;
    players =         (
                    {
            name = "Sean Lee";
            number = 50;
        },
                    {
            name = "Jason Witten";
            number = 82;
        }
    );
    ties = 0;
    wins = 6;
    year = 2010;
}
```

)

So it looks like the JSON parser worked... but I can't figure out how to get the one-to-many PlayerInfo into sqlite.

I know the  seasonInfo.players = [obj objectForKey:@"players"];  line is wrong... just not sure what to do here.

Be gentle... I'm an iOS newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got the "outer loop" of teams working, now you just need to add an "inner loop" of players on each team.

Start with the code you have for creating teams, and within your loop:

```
// Other stuff from your code here, omitted for brevity
seasonInfo.ties = [obj objectForKey:@"ties"];
seasonInfo.coach = [obj objectForKey:@"coach"];

// Loop through each player, creating a new PlayerInfo entity for each one:
NSArray *playerArray = [obj objectForKey:@"players"]
[playerArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id playerObj, NSUInteger playerIdx, BOOL *playerStop) {
    PlayerInfo *playerInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PlayerInfo"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];

    playerInfo.seasonInfo = seasonInfo;
    playerInfo.name = [playerObj objectForKey:@"name"];
    playerInfo.number = [playerObj objectForKey:@"number"];
}];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Because you have the inverse relationship set between PlayerInfo and SeasonInfo, you can establish the connection from either end of the relationship, and the other end will be taken care of automatically. In this case, you'd be creating the new PlayerInfo entities and by setting each entity's seasonInfo value, the one-to-many relationship on the SeasonInfo side will be populated.

You can also add individual PlayerInfo objects to the SeasonInfo's players relationship set, but I find that to be more confusing that just adding the relationship from each entity in the many back to the one.